# Add 3D objects to the frame during live shooting

Tags: python, 3d, camera

Let's say I want to add a 3D chair while shooting a room, if I walk around it, then the angle of the chair changes as if it were there. Like filters in the phone where you can replace the face with the face of an animal. Perhaps someone knows what this technology is called and where you can read about it or implement it in my project. Thank you